# Execution time for HMAC-MD5 on a 160 bit data using 128 bit key on a 3GHz CPU

Tags: hmac

I need to know the execution time  for HMAC -MD5 for a 160 bit data using 128 bit key on a 3 Ghz CPU, kindly specify other parameters of the machine like RAM, operating system used etc

Comment: Perhaps 800 CPU cycles if the key is fixed, twice that if it is not. That corresponds to about 0.3 µs on zour 3 GHy CPU. Details depend on the CPU in question. See [eBASH](http://bench.cr.yp.to/results-hash.html)

Comment: @CodesInChaos 800 logic CPU cycles. When special optimization tricks are involved the real CPU cycles can vary (pipelining, instruction fusioning, etc). So the only sure way to find out is to test it. Similar tests are part of standard benchmark kits, and one of my own benchmark kits is not too dissimilar with this - encrypt 1GiB of data with SHA512-HMAC in OFB mode.

Comment: @MaxthonChan I used the cost for hashing 64 bytes (2 blocks) from SUPERCOP on a modern Intel CPU. Since HMAC with fixed key hashes 2 blocks as well, that should be a reasonable approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CPU architecture and instruction set will make a difference, as is the cache. And if the memory bandwidth is too limiting it may bottleneck your system. OS generally don't make a difference unless the system is under extreme load.

Comment: I just need to know the execution time  for the above mentioned algorythm,  ,on any 3 ghz CPU and would really appretiate if the cpu architecture, code language  and other specifications  of the machine used is mentioned

Comment: @SARA You will have to code and run it yourself on actual target hardware to find out - there are too many variables to control. This execution time is actually a pretty good benchmark of the available target platforms, run them and report back with exact platform configurations and execution times. One of my benchmark kits include encrypting 1GiB of data using SHA512-HMAC in OFB mode, which is a similar scenario as this one.